# Why is my code duplicating the name of a button?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have tried to customise my buttons in unity, but for some reason the name of the button is duplicated in the corner of the button, and cannot be customised/deleted. How do I get rid of the duplicate?

```
public GUIStyle style;
public Texture Load;
public Texture backGroundTexture;



void OnGUI() {
    GUI.skin.button = style;
    GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), backGroundTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit);
    //GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, 200, 73), Load, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit);
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2.5f,Screen.height / 5 ,200,73), "Load")) {
        Application.LoadLevel(1);       
    }
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2.5f, Screen.height / 3, Screen.width / 5, Screen.height/10), "Exit Game")) {
        Application.Quit();     
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show a screenshot of what's happening?

Comment: [The text from buttons is duplicated and appears in corners](http://i.imgur.com/L8z4VBw.png)

Comment: Is that center text part of the textures you're using on the buttons?

Comment: no the textures are without text, just a button image

Comment: Try fiddling with your guistyle. Not too familiar with them but maybe there's some option in there that's causing the issue.

Comment: i tried doing that and none of the options seems to change the text in the corner, im just playing around with unity and I dont want to put the text on textures

Comment: best guess: you have this GUI script running on two or more game objects at the same time

Comment: Old UI or new UI? -- Why did I even ask that? :facepalm:

Comment: new UI, and no I dont have ir tunning on two objects because there is only a camera and one game object